# What does Interleaved Event mean in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I read through the react.js source code and I found a keyword: interleaved event. What does it mean exactly? Can someone explain it to me? Thanks a lot

Comment: Where did you get this information about `Interleaved Event`. 

In reactjs all events are SyntheticEvent. These are as per standard event definition, so you don’t need to worry about cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Hi, I get the information about `Interleaved Event` by reading through the react source code. For example, in react/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberWorkLoop.new.js, there is a comment in function `requestUpdateLane` mentioned about `Interleaved Event`. I googled but didn't find some helpful information